# Error 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND in dns.js' in Google Action

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I plan to use Google Action to retrieve some web page content.
I try to use 'request' and 'read-art', but I encounter 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND in dns.js'.
The webpage url is in https://jiabailie.github.io/, below is the code segment.

```
    read(webPage, function(err, art, options, resp) {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }
    var content = art.html;
    let inputPrompt = app.buildInputPrompt(true, '<speak>' + content + '</speak>', NO_INPUTS);
    app.ask(inputPrompt);
    })
```

Comment: Have you enabled billing for your google cloud console?

Comment: Yes, it has been enabled.

Comment: Since the URL you have mentioned is reachable, I don't  doubt anything else other than the billing and payment method. This sort of error I have usually encountered only when there's an issue with the billing setup in my projects.

Comment: Can you describe your hosting environment? Are you using the Dialogflow fulfillment editor, Firebase Functions or something else?

Comment: For this, I have implement that using Google Cloud Function.